# How can i get the tile values (x and y) for zoom level 25 in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an app which loads some custom tiles on zoom level 25, but google maps zoom level is limited to 21. How can i get tile values for zoom level 25(no matter whether google map tiles available or not in that zoom level)?.

Comment: `but google maps zoom level is limited to 21` - you just answered yourself, no?

Answer (score 0):

X and Y values for a tile are simply and index of which position of the world you are. 
In this page you can see a very good explanation on how the tiling scheme works:
http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/
At the end of the page there is some code that can help you calculating the bounds or the indexes of tiles (It's python).
GoogleMaps tiles are limited to lev 21 but you should be able to zoom further if you disable google maps tiles (set map type to GoogleMap.TYPE_NONE).
The below code shows how I use the x,y and z to get the tiles coordinates (Using a wms service), it should be easy for you if you know the bounds and the zoom to have the x and y:

```
protected double[] getBoundingBox(int x, int y, int zoom) {
    double tileSize = MAP_SIZE / Math.pow(2, zoom);
    double minx = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_X] + x * tileSize;
    double maxx = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_X] + (x + 1) * tileSize;
    double miny = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_Y] - (y + 1) * tileSize;
    double maxy = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_Y] - y * tileSize;

    double[] bbox = new double[4];
    bbox[MINX] = minx;
    bbox[MINY] = miny;
    bbox[MAXX] = maxx;
    bbox[MAXY] = maxy;

    return bbox;
}
```

Further, if you have a specific point (like the center of your view), in meters coordinates, you can get the corresponding tile given the zoom:

```
private TileDataInfo getTileByCoordinate(double xmeters, double ymeters, int zoomLevel) {
    final double tileDim = MAP_SIZE / Math.pow(2d, zoomLevel);

    final int tileX = (int) ((pointX - TILES_ORIGIN[0]) / tileDim);
    final int tileY = (int) ((TILES_ORIGIN[1] - pointY) / tileDim);

    return new TileDataInfo(tileX, tileY, zoomLevel);
}
```

Where:

```
private static final double[] TILES_ORIGIN = {-20037508.34789244, 20037508.34789244};
    // Size of square world map in meters, using WebMerc projection.
    private static final double MAP_SIZE = 20037508.34789244 * 2;
   private static final double ORIGIN_SHIFT = Math.PI * 6378137d;
```

To get the meters of the coordinates from LatLng data:

```
/**
     * Transform the lat in meters
     *
     * @param latitude the latitude of map
     * @return meters of y coordinate
     */
    private double inMetersYCoordinate(double latitude) {
        if (latitude < 0) {
            return -inMetersYCoordinate(-latitude);
        }
        return (Math.log(Math.tan((90d + latitude) * Math.PI / 360d)) / (Math.PI / 180d)) * ORIGIN_SHIFT / 180d;
    }

    /**
     * Transform the lng in meters
     *
     * @param longitude the longitude of map
     * @return meters of x coordinate
     */
    private double inMetersXCoordinate(double longitude) {
        return longitude * ORIGIN_SHIFT / 180.0;
    }
```

Hope it help!